# Trouble with setting the objective function in BayesianOptimization tuner in keras_tuner

Tags: tf.keras, bayesian, keras-tuner

I'm trying to tune hyperparameters for an LSTM model in Keras using Keras tuner's BayesianOptimization tuner. I keep getting error messages that seem to object to what I put in the objective argument when I instantiate the tuner. Here's my code:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense
    from kerastuner.tuners import BayesianOptimization
    from kerastuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameters
    from kerastuner import Objective
    
    def build_model(hp):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(hp.Int("input_unit", min_value=20, max_value=100, step=20),
                       batch_input_shape=(149,1,1), stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
        for i in range(hp.Int("n_layers", 1, 2)):
            model.add(LSTM(hp.Int(f"lstm_{i}_units", min_value=20, max_value=100, step=20),
                           stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(Dropout(hp.Float("Dropout_rate", min_value=0, max_value=0.5, step=0.1)))
        model.add(Dense(1))
        model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",
                      optimizer=hp.Choice("optimizer", values=["rmsprop", "adam"]),
                      metrics=[keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(name="rmse")])
        return model
    
    tuner = BayesianOptimization(build_model,
                                 objective=Objective("root_mean_squared_error", direction="min"),
                                 max_trials=5,
                                 executions_per_trial=1)
    
    tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=149, shuffle=False, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Below is the message I get back. As you can see, it appears that the code executes at least partially, since I'm getting a message back about what hyperparameters perform best so far, and I get the summary of the epochs. After that, a long line of error messages with the last one seeming to be related to the objective argument. Is the issue with how I am specifying the objective function when I instantiate the tuner, or is there some other issue?

```
    INFO:tensorflow:Reloading Oracle from existing project ./untitled_project/oracle.json
    INFO:tensorflow:Reloading Tuner from ./untitled_project/tuner0.json
    
    Search: Running Trial #3
    
    Value             |Best Value So Far |Hyperparameter
    20                |40                |input_layer
    1                 |0                 |middle_layers
    0.1               |0.2               |dropout_rate
    
    WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).layer_with_weights-1.kernel
    WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).layer_with_weights-1.bias
    WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer.iter
    WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer.decay
    WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer.learning_rate
    WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer.momentum
    WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer.rho
    WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'rms' for (root).layer_with_weights-1.kernel
    WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'rms' for (root).layer_with_weights-1.bias
    WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
    Epoch 1/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 3s 25ms/step - loss: 0.2129 - rmse: 0.4614 - val_loss: 0.2266 - val_rmse: 0.4761
    Epoch 2/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 0.1665 - rmse: 0.4080 - val_loss: 0.2074 - val_rmse: 0.4554
    Epoch 3/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.1618 - rmse: 0.4022 - val_loss: 0.2002 - val_rmse: 0.4474
    Epoch 4/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.1575 - rmse: 0.3969 - val_loss: 0.1906 - val_rmse: 0.4366
    Epoch 5/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.1513 - rmse: 0.3890 - val_loss: 0.1788 - val_rmse: 0.4228
    Epoch 6/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.1421 - rmse: 0.3770 - val_loss: 0.1638 - val_rmse: 0.4047
    Epoch 7/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.1283 - rmse: 0.3583 - val_loss: 0.1440 - val_rmse: 0.3794
    Epoch 8/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.1073 - rmse: 0.3275 - val_loss: 0.1161 - val_rmse: 0.3408
    Epoch 9/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0773 - rmse: 0.2781 - val_loss: 0.0807 - val_rmse: 0.2841
    Epoch 10/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0509 - rmse: 0.2256 - val_loss: 0.0613 - val_rmse: 0.2475
    Epoch 11/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0449 - rmse: 0.2119 - val_loss: 0.0594 - val_rmse: 0.2438
    Epoch 12/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0440 - rmse: 0.2098 - val_loss: 0.0587 - val_rmse: 0.2423
    Epoch 13/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0434 - rmse: 0.2084 - val_loss: 0.0583 - val_rmse: 0.2414
    Epoch 14/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0431 - rmse: 0.2076 - val_loss: 0.0580 - val_rmse: 0.2408
    Epoch 15/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0429 - rmse: 0.2070 - val_loss: 0.0578 - val_rmse: 0.2405
    Epoch 16/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0427 - rmse: 0.2066 - val_loss: 0.0577 - val_rmse: 0.2402
    Epoch 17/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0426 - rmse: 0.2064 - val_loss: 0.0576 - val_rmse: 0.2400
    Epoch 18/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0425 - rmse: 0.2062 - val_loss: 0.0575 - val_rmse: 0.2398
    Epoch 19/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0424 - rmse: 0.2060 - val_loss: 0.0575 - val_rmse: 0.2397
    Epoch 20/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0424 - rmse: 0.2059 - val_loss: 0.0574 - val_rmse: 0.2396
    Epoch 21/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0423 - rmse: 0.2058 - val_loss: 0.0573 - val_rmse: 0.2395
    Epoch 22/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0423 - rmse: 0.2057 - val_loss: 0.0573 - val_rmse: 0.2394
    Epoch 23/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0423 - rmse: 0.2056 - val_loss: 0.0572 - val_rmse: 0.2393
    Epoch 24/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0422 - rmse: 0.2055 - val_loss: 0.0572 - val_rmse: 0.2392
    Epoch 25/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0422 - rmse: 0.2055 - val_loss: 0.0572 - val_rmse: 0.2391
    Epoch 26/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0422 - rmse: 0.2054 - val_loss: 0.0571 - val_rmse: 0.2390
    Epoch 27/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0422 - rmse: 0.2054 - val_loss: 0.0571 - val_rmse: 0.2390
    Epoch 28/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0422 - rmse: 0.2053 - val_loss: 0.0571 - val_rmse: 0.2389
    Epoch 29/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0421 - rmse: 0.2053 - val_loss: 0.0570 - val_rmse: 0.2388
    Epoch 30/30
    29/29 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0421 - rmse: 0.2052 - val_loss: 0.0570 - val_rmse: 0.2388
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    /tmp/ipykernel_371/3389478107.py in <module>
         26                              executions_per_trial=1)
         27 
    ---> 28 tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=149, shuffle=False, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
    
    ~/comp_4447/dst2_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/base_tuner.py in search(self, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
        177 
        178             self.on_trial_begin(trial)
    --> 179             results = self.run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
        180             # `results` is None indicates user updated oracle in `run_trial()`.
        181             if results is None:
    
    ~/comp_4447/dst2_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/tuner.py in run_trial(self, trial, *args, **kwargs)
        292             callbacks.append(model_checkpoint)
        293             copied_kwargs["callbacks"] = callbacks
    --> 294             obj_value = self._build_and_fit_model(trial, *args, **copied_kwargs)
        295 
        296             histories.append(obj_value)
    
    ~/comp_4447/dst2_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/tuner.py in _build_and_fit_model(self, trial, *args, **kwargs)
        221         model = self._try_build(hp)
        222         results = self.hypermodel.fit(hp, model, *args, **kwargs)
    --> 223         return tuner_utils.convert_to_metrics_dict(
        224             results, self.oracle.objective, "HyperModel.fit()"
        225         )
    
    ~/comp_4447/dst2_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/tuner_utils.py in convert_to_metrics_dict(results, objective, func_name)
        266         best_epoch = 0
        267         for epoch, metrics in epoch_metrics.items():
    --> 268             objective_value = objective.get_value(metrics)
        269             # Support multi-objective.
        270             if objective.name not in metrics:
    
    ~/comp_4447/dst2_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/objective.py in get_value(self, logs)
         53             The objective value.
         54         """
    ---> 55         return logs[self.name]
         56 
         57     def better_than(self, a, b):
    
    KeyError: 'root_mean_squared_error'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if :

```
objective=Objective("rmse", direction="min")
```

---

I don't know why it's not working. I tried it just now, modifying a notebook of mine to test, and 'rmse' works.

(p.s. I prefer Optuna though, for huge datasets, much faster)

Here are some snippets:

```
self.compile_metrics = ['AUC', 'binary_accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall',
                                tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(
                                name='rmse', dtype=None
                                )]
        
self.model.compile(
            optimizer = opt,
            #loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
            loss = 'mean_squared_error',
            metrics = self.compile_metrics,
            steps_per_execution = self.steps_per_execution,
        )

# above are snippets from my_keras_tuner_class


        
dl = my_keras_tuner_class()

tuner = kt.BayesianOptimization(
            dl.model_builder,                  # the hypermodel, found in custom class keras_tuning 
            #objective = 'val_binary_accuracy', # objective to optimize
            objective = kt.Objective("rmse", direction="min"),
            max_trials = nn_trials,            # number of trials
            distribution_strategy = tpu_strategy,
            # this project name (a dir) is created in 'directory', and is used to 
            #     resume tuning if the search is run again
            directory = f'{workdir}',   
            project_name = 'kbayesian',
            # if True, overwrite above directory if search is run again - i.e. don't resume
            overwrite = True
            
            
            
Trial 2 Complete [00h 00m 16s]
rmse: 0.42514675855636597

Best rmse So Far: 0.42514675855636597


display(model.metrics_names)
-output:
['loss', 'auc', 'binary_accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'rmse']


# example trial
9s 453ms/step - loss: 2.5937 - auc: 0.6732 - binary_accuracy: 0.6353 - precision: 0.6174 - recall: 0.6237 - rmse: 0.5435 - val_loss: 1.1624 - val_auc: 0.7197 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6970 - val_precision: 0.7083 - val_recall: 0.8500 - val_rmse: 0.5045
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In trying to figure out what to put in for the objective argument, I did try specifying an Objective like what you show, but was unsuccessful. I did finally get the tuner to "work" by using objective="val_loss"

Comment: That's nice to know, I don't know why, but 'rmse' should work.  I could not show it here in a comment, so I just modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

objective="val_loss" also worked for me. I don't know why but I tried many things and that was the only one that worked.